# getting firebase login to work with react native

Tags: authentication, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to get react native and firebase to work with eachother but no matter where i look all i seem to find is out of date tutorials. 
When i finally was able to initialize my firebase object then the method names that we're being used in other tutorials weren't defined with the object that i had defined. 
I'm at a bit of a loss with this. 
Any help would be massively appreciated. 
Thank you .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {View} from 'react-native';

import * as Firebase from 'firebase';

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '....',
    authDomain: '....',
    databaseURL: 'https://....',
    storageBucket: '...',
};

Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'unique_id');

class LoginProcess extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var fbRef = Firebase;
    }

    login(email, password) {
        if (this.props.onLoginRequested) {
            this.props.onLoginRequested();
        }

        // Firebase.authWithPassword({
        //  'email': email,
        //  'password': password
        // },
        // (error, user_data) => {
        //  if (error) {
        //      console.log('Login Failed. Please try again');
        //  }
        //  else {
        //      AsyncStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(user_data));
        //      console.log(JSON.stringify(user_data))
        //  }
        // });
    }

    render () {
        return (<View/>)
    }
}

module.exports = LoginProcess;
```

Answer (score 2):

ok after some playing around i found this was one way i could achieve what i needed to.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {View} from 'react-native';

import * as Firebase from 'firebase';

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '.....',
    authDomain: '......',
    databaseURL: 'https://......',
    storageBucket: '......',
};

const firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, 'unique_id');

const auth = firebaseApp.auth();

class LoginProcess extends Component {
    login(email, password) {
        if (this.props.onLoginRequested) {
            this.props.onLoginRequested();
        }
        // auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword // for signup
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((data) => {
            if (this.props.onLoginSuccess) {
                this.props.onLoginSuccess(data)
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;

            if (this.props.onLoginError) {
                this.props.onLoginError(error.code, error.message)
            }
        });
    }

    render () {return <View/>;}
}

module.exports = LoginProcess;
```

Answer (score 0):

You already found the solution, but I have it hooked up with Redux like so (also creates user if doesn't already exist)

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
  return (dispatch) => {

dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
  .catch(() => {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
      .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch));
  });
 };
};

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: user
  });
  Actions.main();
};
```

I was also wondering if you have found a way to make it persist login upon re-opening the app?